# How to determine data size is statistically efficient?

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, sample-size, binary-data, sufficient-statistics

I have a question about the data size for probability of default model.
For each consumer, I have a binary bit to indicate whether the client goes default or not (1 is default and 0 is current). And I have the occupation for each consumer (ie, doctor, student). So I can calculate the probability of default for different occupations (#default clients / #total clients), and then continue with my analysis.

The problem here is that for each occupation, it has different size (ie. 1000 clients are students, only 50 clients are doctors). Then how can I say that the population of the group(data points) is statistically sufficient to calculate the probability of default for that occupation?

For example, there is only 1 out of 50 doctors in my database that went default, so does this 2% is correctly reflecting the default behavior of this occupation? If the population is too small, then I don't want to include it in my future analysis. What should be the minimum data size for each group that I can say I'm confident with the outcome?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: There are power calculations for binary outcomes, such as the “pwr” package in R. There might be issues stemming from the clustering you’ve done before the power calculation, however. It would help if you edited your post to expand on how and why you do the clustering.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! the problem here is not about the clustering, maybe I should remove that part. Just assume I have 10 groups and I want to calculate the default ratio for each group. If the population for the group is too small, then the ratio is not correctly reflecting the actual default probability for that group, then I will not consider that group in my future analysis. So I was wondering how can I decide to remove the group due to insufficient population?